# Inject binary PDF into IFrame

Tags: pdf, browser, stream

Having a business web application (in Silverlight but it's irrelevant) I'm looking for a way to show a PDF document to the user that the client has as a binary value. In other words, I want to 'stream' the contents of an IFrame from a local variable. Is this possible and how?

Here is the scenario: the web application is implemented in Silverlight. Different documents (images, reports, etc) are managed by the application, holding them as byte arrays. To display a PDF file to the user, I wish to open an IFrame and load the PDF binary into it so that the browser's built-in PDF capability will handle it.

What I need help with is how to load an array of bytes (held in memory) into that IFrame so that the browser can do it's job.

(Disclaimer: I know it's a strange setup. It has reasons.)